# How to measure memory throughput utilization percentage?

Tags: memory, monitoring, resource-usage

To check the amount of disk space used on Windows, opening `This PC` is enough. To check system-wide disk utilization (how hard the disk is working), one can see it in the Windows 10 Task Manager.

[image: Task Manager]

To check the amount of memory space used, one can also see it in the Task Manager.

How can one view system-wide memory throughput utilization (how hard the RAM is currently working) as percentage on Windows/Linux? Is there software for such a measurement?

Comment: In Linux you can use the `bash` command `free | while read c t u r; do [ $c == Mem: ] && echo "$c $((($u*200+$t)/(2*$t)))%"; done`. The formula rounds up or down to the nearest percentage.

Comment: How hard the RAM is "working"? What do you mean by "working"? If you're looking for read/write throughput to RAM, there is no counter for that.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you just open Task Manager, go to the performance tab and select the "memory" item on the left.

It will then show you how much physical RAM is in use and other statistics such as commit charge.